# Trying to publish Visual Studio project to webserver

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, deployment

I am by no means a programmer, but I was recently tasked with moving our website to a new server, since the website manager quit.  The Visual Studio solution was written in 2008.  I can compile and run the solution, so I'm sure it's working just fine.  But every time I try to publish the solution, either to FTP or to my local hard drive, the .asp webpages get deployed to a sub directory, where on the live site, they are in the root.  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You haven't actually told us what you're doing. Also, do you mean .asp files or .aspx files?

Comment: Honestly, I'm not even sure what I'm doing.  The files created are .aspx pages.  When I try to load one, it errors out, and I'm having issues getting it to display the errors with the " <customErrors mode="Off"/>" tag, but not having much luck.  I was hoping there was a generic way to publish a solution into a website, but I may be out of luck it seems, lol.

Comment: Well, there is, but you need to give some information. The process was different between Visual Studio 2003 and 2010, for instance, and between a Web Site "project" and a web application project. Do you have a .vbproj file in your project? Which version of Visual Studio, IIS, etc?

Comment: The project was written in 2008, I have both 2008 and 2010.  Yes, there is a .vbproj file in the project. My web server is running IIS6 with the option to upgrade to IIS7 if needed.  We're trying to verify that I can get this working before paying for additional hosting, so I'm using a free hosting account through godaddy for testing.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since all of the files used to display the pages are in different sub directories, I'm assuming I'm going to have to create a virtual directory in IIS with all the "Views" directories listed in the path

Comment: In VS2010 you can just right-click your project and use the Publish command.

Comment: I've tried publishing via FTP, then I try to load the default Index.aspx and I get an error.  I've played with it a bit, and created an IIS Virtual Directory, and now I'm getting "Server Application Unavailable"  So I think I'm making progress.  Thanks again for all your help John

Comment: Ok, after spending all day trying different things to fix the "Server Application Unavailable", I think I'm officially lost.  I'm not sure if I setup IIS wrong, or if the IIS manager from godaddy is even letting me do what I think I'm doing.  A Google search for the error yielded little results.  Either the page made no sense, or I just don't understand the language, lol.

Answer (score 0):

When you click on the link to publish in Visual Studio, there is a textbox that gives you the option of where to publish to.

That folder will be the root of the published application. Just move all the files from in there to the web server and you should be good to go!